# Spring Rest Service Post request error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

It may be a basic question related to Spring Rest service Post request

Below is my  Controller mapping code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String addFruits(@RequestBody RequestWrapper fruits) {
     // ...
        System.out.println("test");
        return null;
    }
```

Below is the RequestWrapper class:

```
public class RequestWrapper{
 List<String> ids;
 String languageCode;
...
}
```

Now if in advanced Chrome rest client, with content-type as application/json
if I post the following request :

```
["ids": [{ "1","2","3","4"}]
,

"languageCode" : "en_US"
]
```

I get the following error:

Error 400: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 400

Any clue as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Enable DEBUG logs for Spring and check its output.

Comment: This `["ids": [{ "1","2","3","4"}]` is invalid JSON.

Comment: Trying {"ids": [{ "1","2","3","4"},

"languageCode" : "en_US"}

Comment: Check using this {
    "ids": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "languageCode": "en_US"
} you can validate your json in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: great thank you @AlejandroAgapitoBautista for giving the json validation link

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you  the issue got resolved with the correct json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to an incorrect JSON format in the actual question.

With due help from Soitirios Delimanolis and Alejandro Agapito Bautista could correct the json format and the code worked.

The correct json format is:

```
{ "ids": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], "languageCode": "en_US" }
```

Also learnt from Alejandro Agapito Bautista's the json validation link
 [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)